# Does "homeomorphic" depend on the topology?

Tags: general-topology

Does "to be homeomorphic" depend on the topology ?

For example let $(C,T)$ the circle with the topology induced by $\mathbb R$ and $(V,T')$ an other topological space. We suppose that $C\cong V$. If we gives an other topology to $C$ (for example, the quotient topology, i.e. $C=[0,1]/_{0\sim 1}$), will we still have that $C\cong V$ ?

Comment: The whole point of homeomorphisms is that it depends on the topology. What you have is because the quotient topology on C is homeomorphic to the induced topology.

Comment: Ok, so here it work, but it's not true in general, right ? @Rise

Comment: Take the reals with the usual topology, and the reals with the discrete topology. It is easy to verify these are not homeomorphic.

Comment: I wouldn't quite say that $C = [0,1]/(0 \sim 1)$ is a new topology for $C$. Rather it is a new model of the space precisely in the sense that it is a new (set,topology) pair that is homeomorphic to the circle. (Why I say it is not the same is because the set has changed as well). But homeomorphism is an equivalence relation.

Comment: Homeomorphism depends totally on the topology, not just on the underlying set.

Answer (score 0):

Of course ! It's very easy to prove that $(C,\mathcal T_1)\cong (C,\mathcal T_2)$ where $\mathcal T_1$ is the topology induced by $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathcal T_2$ the quotient topology.

Comment: Ok for here, but in general ?